# How to install Ubuntu in Dell XPS 17?

Tags: installation, nvidia, dell

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to Linux. I have a basic understanding but struggle with the more complex things. I am using a Dell XPS 17 (L207X) which has a core i7 processor and Nvidia GT555M hybrid card and cannot get a successful installation of any Ubuntu distro from 11.Xx upwards.

Could anyone offer any help / advice / step by step instructions to help me get a successful installation of at least 11.10 as that is the distro I was using on my old laptop?

Comment: Can you please post your problems/error messages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm about to put Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell XPS 17 (l702x) 1080p 3D model. From what I've read, you need to start with the ["alternate CD"](http://gb.releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso), which is less user friendly, from an installation point-of-view (text mode), but is supposed to work. I've linked to the [64-bit version](http://gb.releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso).

All Ubuntu 12.04 iso images can be found at http://gb.releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/.

Just to pre-empt any issues you might have once installed, I'm also including the following links (no particular order):

- [Ubuntu 11.04 on XPS 17](http://www.cmdematos.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneric-on-dell-xps17-l702x.html) (useful info)
- [Fixing Intel HDA audio on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto) (The older/outdated info on this page was deemed **better** than the new linked method, by an XPS user.
- [More on fixing Intel HDA audio on Ubuntu](http://www.dkvermalinux.in/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-sound-problem.html)
- [Fixing Intel n-1000 wireless WIFI card driver on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131912/wireless-not-working-on-dell-xps-17-after-installing-12-04#165194)
- [Fixing Intel n-1000 wireless WIFI card sleep behaviour on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153092/cant-find-intel-wireless-n-1000-after-waking-from-sleep)
- [Fixing screen brightness control on Dell XPS 17 under Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/762670)

I hope this of use to you and the community.

Cheers

Rich

Comment: Thankyou for your advice, seems that this will work for me. Ive read through everything to make sure i'm clear on what i need to do. My only question at this point is, is it possible to create a dual boot with the alternate cd? The only reason i ask is i still need to have windows as a dual boot option for a few bits of hardware i own.

Many thanks again,

Steve

Comment: @Cybercore - Steve, shouldn't be a problem dual booting, I've read that it's best to install Windows first (I've not ran dual-boot myself for years). 'StarbuckSteve' over at tonymacx86.com has this [post](http://www.tonymacx86.com/viewtopic.php?t=23185) which includes a PDF guide on triple-booting Windows 7, Ubuntu and OS X on a XPS 17. I'm not suggesting you want/need OSX, however, he seems to suggest that having Ubuntu installed makes that easier. You might need to set up an account to get to his files. Let us know how you get on, cheers, Rich.