# Problems with Intel Centrino Wirless-N 1000

Tags: wireless, intel

I have been having problems with setting up my wifi on Ubuntu 12.04. I installed it last week and since then have had the same problem as most in that the connection was never stable and had a pop up asking for password every 20 seconds or so. I have tried adding the `options iwlagn 11n_disable=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf` but never got it working. In the process of going through methods found on this site I appear to have taken the wifi card off.

I now have a network that is unclaimed for `wlan0` and is not seen in `iwconfig`.

`$ lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 124d (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

`$ sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f3b00000-f3b01fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: 84:8f:69:b9:40:bc
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.1.80 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:50 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f3004000-f3004fff memory:f3000000-f3003fff
```

`$ iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 2):

I outline a potential fix for this in post [https://askubuntu.com/questions/131912/wireless-not-working-on-dell-xps-17-after-installing-12-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131912/wireless-not-working-on-dell-xps-17-after-installing-12-04#165194), I'm copy the answer below:

I've got a Dell XPS 17 (l702x) with an n-1000 I'd like to get working under Ubuntu 12.04 (once I install it). So, lending heavily from [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941350#3):

The fix seems to involve downgrading the n-1000's firmware.

Please downgrade the firmware with [iwlwifi-1000-ucode-128.50.3.1.tgz](http://intellinuxwireless.org/iwlwifi/downloads/iwlwifi-1000-ucode-128.50.3.1.tgz) (for ease, save it to your desktop). You can right-click it and select 'Extract' or issue the following at a terminal prompt:

```
tar xzvf ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-1000-ucode-128.50.3.1.tgz
```

Again, in the terminal, back up the current firmware:

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.bak
```

Now copy over the downloaded firmware:

```
cd Desktop/iwlwifi-1000-ucode-128.50.3.1/
cp iwlwifi-1000-3.ucode iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
sudo cp iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode /lib/firmware
sudo modprobe -r iwlagn
sudo modprobe iwlagn
```

Now let's see what happened under the hood:

```
dmesg | tail -n20
```

This has been tested and confirmed in the [original post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941350#3), and is said to be a permanent fix (i.e. is still working after a reboot).

best of luck!

Cheers

Rich

Comment: The link leads nowhere. It leads back to this post. Please specify a full solution or fix the link.

Comment: You live up to the name ObsessiveFOSS, I'd copied and pasted the wrong URL, updated it within 2 mins, apologies for not being as quick as you, do you think you could give me my 2 points back, really?

Comment: Yes, I have removed thew downvote.

Comment: It is a good practice to copy and paste the answer (you should also link the source) as it is faster to find and check.

Comment: Answer updated and suggestion duly noted ;-)